# How can we authenticate page-backed instagram ad accounts

Tags: facebook, instagram, facebook-marketing-api

We are having issues enabling our customers to authenticate their page-backed instagram ad account credentials in order to manage ads in our app. We are stumped trying to figure out what's going wrong, as the authentication works for some customers but not for others.

In the error we receive from Facebook, it says that they don't have the right CREATE_ADS permissions. But in the cases where it's not working, we have verified that the user attempting to authenticate is a Facebook page admin (for the page backing the instagram account) and is an ad account admin.

Is there another type of permission the user needs to have? And/or anything else we need to be validating for a user here?

Answer (score 1):

This is not clearly specified by Facebook. I would suggest you to use:

`/instagram_accounts` and if this doesn't return any result then you should fall back to
`/page_backed_instagram_accounts`

Also, note that `/instagram_accounts` works on ad accounts also.

Comment: I had the same issue, querying against graph API, You are right. I am receiving a valid instagram account for "instagram_accounts " but an invalid for "page_backed_instagram_accounts".